# Laravel where() inside a whereHas() access other side table column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause, relation, with-statement

Sorry for the messy title, i didnt knew how to describe it.
So i got three tables [tables in re model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyEQR.png): students, groups, and the table that relates them called courses.

Im trying to get every "student" that has no group assigned or that has assigned a group with a year greater than 2019, i got this code so far, but i cant access the year column, i tried with the "with()" method but i got no luck, any ideas?
My models on laravel:

Student:

```
public function courses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Course::class, 'id_student');
}
```

Group:

```
public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Course::class, 'id_group');
    }
```

Course:

```
public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Student::class, 'id_student');
    }

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Group::class, 'id_group');
}
```

My query:

```
$students_noassigned = Student::whereHas('courses', function ($query) {
            $query->where('year', '>', 2010);
        })
            ->doesntHave('courses', 'or')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to set a relationship directly between Student and Group (Belongs To Many) via the pivot you could try this:

```
$students_noassigned = Student::whereHas('courses.group', function ($query) {
    $query->where('year', '>', 2010);
})->orDoesntHave('courses')->get();
```

Get students that have courses that have a group with year > 2010 or doesn't have any courses, no groups assigned.